# Want to Use IDisposable interface for HttpWebResponse in Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, idisposable

I am trying to use HttpWebResponse in powershell, and want to dispose the response object, however not sure how to do it in Powershell.

Trying to converting below C# code to PowerShell.

```
HttpWebResponse response = // assigned from somewhere
IDisposable disposableResponse = response as IDisposable;

disposableResponse.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
    $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://www.google.com") -as [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]
    $response = $request.GetResponse() -as [System.Net.HttpWebResponse]

    $disposableResponse = $response -as [System.IDisposable]
    $disposableResponse.Dispose()
```

But HttpWebResponse already has Dispose method because of WebResponse inheritance.

Comment: Thanks wallybh, I tried this but it gives me below error, I think .NET 4.0 doesn't have Dispose.
Method invocation failed because [System.Net.HttpWebResponse] doesn't contain a
method named 'Dispose'.

Comment: Strange. MSDN documentation (for .net 4.0) says HttpWebResponse has Dispose medhod. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: even after execute "$response -as [System.IDisposable]" don't worked?

Comment: Yes, Even after setting response object as IDisposable. It's giving the error .

Comment: As the Idisposable is explicit interface this may be not getting implemented correctly in power shell.